# Fatal error with NuSoap 1.94 with PHP 5.2.17 making a soap client call

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I'm getting an error message when making a call to an xBase++ based web server that is acting as a web service (not using WSDL) when trying to make a soapclient call to it using NuSoap 1.94 with PHP 5.2.17.  This exact same code works with NuSOAP 1.94 on PHP 4.  Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Note (I had to remove the https:// part of the addresses from the error message below - I was getting an error posting saying I needed 10 reputation to post 2 links or more)

Thanks,

Salar

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'xxx.xxx.com:55055' : failed to load external entity "xxx.xxx.com:55055" in /hsphere/local/home/xxx/xxx.com/phpinvent/inc/functions/xmsg.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /hsphere/local/home/xxx/xxx.com/phpinvent/inc/functions/xmsg.php(34): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://xxx.xxx...') #1 /hsphere/local/home/xxx/xxx.com/phpinvent/xmsgtest.php(15): XMsg('LOGIN', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /hsphere/local/home/xxx/xxx.com/phpinvent/inc/functions/xmsg.php on line 34

Here's the code of my test page, and the xmsg function:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// include configuration
require_once('inc/config.php');
require_once('inc/nusoap/nusoap.php'); // include the NuSOAP classes

$xmsg_param[0][0] = "userid";
$xmsg_param[0][1] = "TEST";
$xmsg_param[1][0] = "password";
$xmsg_param[1][1] = "TEST";

$result = XMsg("LOGIN", $xmsg_param);
echo("<br>resulttxt: ".$result['xmsg_resulttxt']);
echo("<br>Sessionid: ".$result['sessionid']);

?>

<?php
// XMsg *************************************************************************
// This function is used to send a message through the robust, connectionless message system
function XMsg($xm_type, $xm_parameters, $xm_target = XMSG_DEFAULT_GATEWAY, $xm_mode = XMSG_DEFAULT_MODE)
{
    // Parameters:
    // xm_type - C - mandatory – type of message being sent
    // xm_parameters - A - optional - 2 dimensional array of name/value pairs that will be sent to the target with the message
    // xm_target - C - optional - target - currently supports only URLs of AutoMate agents - defaults to gateway
    // xm_mode - C - optional - tokens that allow for modification of the message - currently defaults to #SOAP# to send via SOAP
    // Returns:
    // xm_result - A - array of name/value pairs returned from the target in same format as xm_target
    $xm_SOAPagent   = '';       // SOAP Envelope Object - Request
    $xm_SOAPresult  = '';       // SOAP Envelope Object - Response
    $xm_SOAPclass   = '';
    $xm_retrynum    = 0;        // Number of retries attempted
    $xm_retry       = true;     // Continue retrying?
    $xm_result      = Array();  // Array of results returned by XMsg
    $xm_numparams   = 0;        // Number of parameters passed to XMsg
    $xm_I           = 0;        // FOR Loop Counter
    // Initialize Parameters
    $xm_parameters  = (gettype($xm_parameters) == "array" ? $xm_parameters : array());

    // check if mandatory parameters are passed
    // xm_type must be character and not empty
    if (gettype($xm_type)=="string" && !empty($xm_type)) {
       switch($xm_mode)
       {
          case "SOAP":
              // open SOAP envelope and initialize
              echo("calling xm_target: ".$xm_target."<br>");
              $soapclient = new soapclient($xm_target);

              $soapparam = array();

              // create and pass xmsg structure - NOTE: this section is specialized to PHP
              $soapparam['xmsg_id'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_source'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_target'] = $xm_target;
              $soapparam['xmsg_session'] = $_SESSION['SESSIONID'];
              $soapparam['xmsg_userid'] = $_SESSION['USERID'];
              $soapparam['xmsg_websessid'] = session_id();
              $soapparam['xmsg_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
              $soapparam['xmsg_status'] = 'SENT';
              $soapparam['xmsg_type'] = $xm_type;
              $soapparam['xmsg_result'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_resulttxt'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_date'] = date("m/d/y");
              $soapparam['xmsg_time'] = date("H:i:s");
              $soapparam['xmsg_datereceive'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_timereceive'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_dateresponse'] = '';
              $soapparam['xmsg_timeresponse'] = '';

              // count parameters and add to SOAP Envelope
              $xm_numparams = count($xm_parameters);
              for ($xm_I = 0; $xm_I < $xm_numparams; $xm_I++) {
                  echo("setting soapparam[".$xm_parameters[$xm_I][0]."] to :".$xm_parameters[$xm_I][1]);
                  $soapparam[$xm_parameters[$xm_I][0]] = $xm_parameters[$xm_I][1];
              }

              // SOAP retry loop start - retry until xm_retry is false - set to false when call succeeds or max # retries exceeded
              do {

                 // run remote SOAP call for RemoteCall as specified in
                 $xm_result = $soapclient->call('XMsg',$soapparam);
                 // check for fault
                 echo ("Fault: ".$xm_result['FAULT']."<br>");
                 echo ("1 Faultcode: ".$xm_result['faultcode']."<br>");
                 if (empty($xm_result['faultcode'])) {
                     echo('<hr>'.'<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($soapclient->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>');
                     echo('<hr>'.'<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($soapclient->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>');
                    $xm_retry  = false;
                    // update status / response date / time
                    $xm_result['xmsg_status'] = "RECEIVED";
                    $xm_result['xmsg_dateresponse'] = date("m/d/y");
                    $xm_result['xmsg_timeresponse'] = date("H:i:s");
                 } else {
                     echo("2 faultcode: ".$xm_result['faultcode']);
                 }
                 // SOAP Call retry handling
                 if ($xm_retry) {
                    // increase the SOAP comm retry counter to count the number of retries made
                    $xm_retrynum++;
                    // check if the maximum number of retries has been reached
                    if ($xm_retrynum <= XMSG_NUMRETRY) {
                       sleep(XMSG_RETRYDELAY); // delay for set number of seconds
                    } else {
                       $xm_retry = false;
                    }
                 }
              } while ($xm_retry);
            break;
        default:
          // no other message type handling currently
        }
    }
}

return $xm_result;
// XMsg *************************************************************************
```

Comment: Off topic, but please be aware that PHP 5.2 has been out of support for several years now, and has a number of known security bugs that will not be fixed. You should make it a priority to try to upgrade to a supported version. (and note that even 5.3 is nearly at the end of support now as well!)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. Your web server can't see the location the WSDL is hosted at. Can you hit the location if you copy the WSDL url and paste it into your browser? You should check that the URL you are using is correct, and whether your web server can even see that location. If not you will need to remedy that before it will work.

Comment: Garry - the server we are doing the SOAP call on doesn't have a WSDL - is it possible to use NuSOAP to make a SOAP call without using WSDL?  It seemed to work fine in PHP4 - we only ran into problems with PHP5.

Comment: As far as I am aware you don't need a WSDL to use NuSOAP, I just thought that might be how it was being consumed, silly assumption. You need to check the SOAP end point is working and accessible from the server the SOAP request is coming from.

Comment: @GarryWelding I am having the exact problem. My request is not WSDL. How can I check if the end point is working and accessble?

Comment: You would need to go onto the server that you're script is running from and try to access the service via the command line. A simple ping to one of the end points might show if it's accessible or not. Failing that you'll have to craft the curl request yourself and try it.